# Freely available old-style serif fonts with multiple weights

Tags: fonts, typography

When I typeset text, I love to be able to choose from a large array of different weights (and, if possible, expansions). Having light and semi-bold variants in addition to the regular and bold weights really help broaden one's choices for setting type elegantly. For long-running text, I am quite partial to old-style serifs, and to [Arno Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arno_%28typeface%29) and [Minion Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minion_%28typeface%29) in particular.

However, those two are commercial fonts. I am thus looking for a **good set of free old-style serif fonts including three or four weights**. (Free as is free beer or free speech, I'm trying not to set the bar too high!).

Comment: "freely available" is the sticker. Most type designers won't do all that work and then give it away. :)

Comment: @Skaught I know, but there is a growing number of available such fonts… and at least one (Libertine) has multiple weights

Answer (score 3):

Some other sources of free (and sometimes good) fonts:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ and http://www.searchfreefonts.com/

Few examples: [ALEGREYA](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/alegreya), [CARDO](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Cardo), [CAUDEX](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/caudex), [CRIMSON](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Crimson) ...

Answer (score 2):

[Metafont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont) is Donald Knuth's font description language supporting obscene numbers of parameters, including multiple weights ("asking an artist to become enough of a mathematician to understand how to write a font with 60 parameters is too much"). The most-widely-used Metafont font is Computer Modern, which, unsurprisingly, is Modern rather than old-style.

However, there are apparently some old-style Metafont fonts available. Looking through [one old list (1997)](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/fonts-faq/metafont-list/), I see one called Pandora described as "a little like Palatino", which is old-style. More information on this font: [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/pandora), [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/pandora/).

See also [http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/fonts/metafont.html](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ebeebe/fonts/metafont.html), which lists some Metafont fonts, and the [LaTeX font catalogue list of fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html) (most probably not Metafont).

---

[Gentium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentium) is definitely old-style, and its [Gentium Basic](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Gentium_basic) variant comes in 4 weights (regular, book, bold, book bold), where the Book weights are slightly heavier:

[image: Gentium Basic] [image: Gentium Book Basic]

The Basic fonts have a reduced character repertoire, but the project plans to support book weights for the entire font:

> The main Gentium family will eventually have a complete matching Book weight, along with matching italics.
>
> Our next major effort is completing bold and bold italic weights of Gentium Plus alongside a new Gentium Book Plus family. These new weights are currently available for Gentium Basic/Gentium Book Basic.")

Answer (score 1):

DaFont.com has many free fonts, and will list by category. 
For example, all the serif fonts are at:

http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=502

From there, you can list only the free ones by clicking "more options" in the bar between "Basic>Serif" and the actual fonts, and checking the appropriate boxes.

Comment: From there, finding one with many weights is a matter of trial and error. You're going to have to download a handful and see.

Comment: Regarding weights, I scrolled over 30 fonts and only found 1 that matches my criteria: Linux Libertine :(

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Merriweather](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Merriweather) on Google's webfonts. It is not strictly "old style" in the Venetian/Garalde tradition but I think it will do what you're after.

Obviously, you can use it for web, but you can also download for comps and print work. It is not a thoroughly programmed OpenType font like you would expect when handing over cash but you're *not* handing over cash.

For the price, you will not find a finer piece of type design.

Comment: It's missing a lot of OT features as you mention, but the bigger issue is that the x height of Merriweather is insane relative to other fonts for print. Looking good on paper is an express non-goal of its author: https://ebensorkin.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/why-and-how-i-am-making-merriweather/